# Is $\sum \cos(n \pi) \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ conditionally or absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

> Is $\sum \cos(n \pi) \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ conditionally or absolutely
>   convergent?

**My Working**

Clearly, $\sum \cos(n \pi) \frac{n}{n^2+1} = \sum (-1)^n \frac{n}{n^2+1}$, and it can be shown by using the alternating series test that this series converges. So it at least converges conditionally.

Now to test for absolute convergence, I need to test whether $\sum |(-1)^n \frac{n}{n^2+1}| = \sum \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ converges or not. I've got a gut feeling that this series is divergent, but I can't seem to be able to prove it. I've tried the comparison and ratio tests but to no avail.

Comment: Note $n/(n^2+1)\ge n/(n^2+n^2)=1/(2n)$.

Comment: @user, your first part is correct, and the second one follows from David's comment above...and your gut feeling.

Comment: Hah so simple, can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply notice that $\frac{n}{n^2+1}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, hence the series doesn't converge absolutely.